# Promises, Angular2 and scope

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, promise

I have an Angular2 component that needs to get an ID from an external service. This service returns a promise so I need to await the Promise to get the data back before proceeding. The component looks something like this:

```
export class AddTodoComponent implements OnInit {
    public todo:TodoItem;
    constructor(private todoService: TodoService,
                private router: Router) {
        this.todo = new TodoItem();
     }


    saveItem(){
        this.todoService.getItems().then(t=>{
            this.todo.item.id = t.length;
            this.todoService.addItem(this.todo);
        });

    }
}
```

However, when the saveItem function executes, I get an error in the console as follows:

> EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot set
>   property 'id' of undefined

The service just returns a `Promise.resolve(data)` with the items I need, and I have verified that is returning the data as expected. However, it now seems that inside the ‘*thennable*’ of the promise I can no longer access `this.todo`, assumedly because this now refers to the promise rather than the class.

What is the correct/preferred means of solving this problem?

Comment: This is javascript?

Comment: Yep, welcome to the new world of Angular2, ES6 and Promises witha sprinkling of Typescript :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not to do with the value of `this` - it still refers to the `AddTodoComponent` class instance thanks to the use of "fat arrow" functions (`=>`).

Instead, the problem seems to be that there is no `item` property of `this.todo`, instead, so you can't then set `this.todo.item.id`.

Answer (score 3):

Because the `todo` is the **item**

```
this.todo = new TodoItem();
```

the `this.todo.item` *(the property `item` of the `TodoItem` instance)*... is undefined. So, it should be init first *(anyhow, inside of constructor, or outside as below)*

```
this.todo.item=  this.todo.item || {} ; // just init item
this.todo.item.id = t.length;
```

Answer (score 2):

The error does not indicate `this` to not point to the current instance of `AddTodoComponent` but instead that `item` of `this.todo` is undefined. The error seems to be in `new TodoItem()` not to define `item`.